# Cannot get /api/users/logout direction in NodeJS/express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to implement a register/login application with token based authentication. I am using JWT/express modules of NodeJS. Everything works fine such as login and reaching other routes after logging in. However, I cannot log out. I tried get/post/ requests but still I get this:

```
Cannot GET /api/users/logout
```

and

```
Cannot POST /api/users/logout
```

status of localhost is 404: Not Found and here is my code

```
router.post(`/logout`,  (req,res,next) =>{

    if(myToken !== ""){

        jwt.verify(myToken, `privatekey`, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Token is not valid anymore' });
            } else {
               routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send(400,`You are not logged in!`);
    }
});
```

myToken is a variable that I use to keep jwt token after logging in.

Comment: That is because the endpoint `/api/users/logout` is not available. Please recheck  your middleware routes  `/api/users`. Also i doubt how are you getting `myToken`. I believe you need to get that from the req.headers (best practice) or req.body (not so best but will do the job).  Thanks

Comment: Similarly i have also seen some people passing token as path parameters like `/api/users/logout/your_jwt_token` if this  is the case then you need to update `/logout/:token` in your route file. If you are passing token as route parameter on just `/logout` route this will also lead to Cannot `GET|POST /api/users/logout`.

Comment: Please post how you are using the `router` in the question, like `app.use('/api/user', router)` or something.

Comment: For the first comment there is a middleware function and the endpoint is available. I just want to try keeping token inside. However, I fixed problem by re-arranging order of post operations but I cannot get logic, why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in one my node application.It occurred because I have typed wrong url such as instead of typing http://localhost:3000/logout I have typed  http://localhost:3000/logut. Make sure that there is no syntax error in your case.